EM junction conditions from Faraday tensor
In classical electrodynamics, we have the Maxwell's junction conditions:
$$
\mathbf{n}\cdot[\mathbf{B}]=0
$$
$$
\mathbf{n}\cdot[\mathbf{D}]=\Sigma
$$
$$
\mathbf{n}\times[\mathbf{H}]=\mathbf{K}
$$
$$
\mathbf{n}\times[\mathbf{E}]=\mathbf{0}
$$
where $\Sigma$ and $\mathbf{K}$ are surface charges and current, respectively, and $[]$ denotes a jump across the surface of discontinuity.
In principle, one should be able to find the above from the Faraday tensor. The only source I could find on this is: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01698208 (eq. 17) which isn't really motivated.
Is there a proof of the junction conditions for the components of $F_{\alpha\beta}$?

such a set of equations is necessarily incomplete. You absolutely need the constitutive relations linking E and D, B and H, if not more complicated relations. And even then, it is incredibly difficult to solve.
